# exclude latest date pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have df that looks like this:

```
      Date          Value
 49     2018-11    6
 50     2018-12    8
 51     2018-12    2
 52     2018-12    5
 53     2018-12    2
 54     2018-12    14
 55     2019-01    8
 56     2019-01    20
 57     2019-01    5
 58     2019-02    2
 59     2019-02    5
 61     2019-02    14
 62     2019-02    2
 60     2019-02    12
 63     2019-02    8
 64     2019-02    1
```

My date field in my data has been converted to datetime. I was wondering on how I can exclude the max date (e.g '2019-02'). I want compare the change between the entire total of Value (all dates) in comparison to  the entire total of Vale minus the latest month of data, to understand the change.

Is there a way to do this without specifically calling out the date (e.g '2019-02')? For example I've tried using loc to filter out the max date on my dataframe but keep getting errors and have also tried setting the index as date.

Is it possible to call out and filter out the max date using loc? I ask because I would like to create a monthly report and not have to manually change the date (e.g '2019-02'), in the code every time I would like to refresh the analysis.

Thank you for any help/suggestions.

Kind regards,

Comment: If your `Date` column is always in order, you could just use `df.iloc[:-1`]

Comment: also works, thanks so much! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert column to datetimes and filter all rows with maximal datetimes by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and filter all rows not equal by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) with `max` value:

```
d = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m')

df = df[d.ne(d.max())]
print (df)
       Date  Value
49  2018-11      6
50  2018-12      8
51  2018-12      2
52  2018-12      5
53  2018-12      2
54  2018-12     14
55  2019-01      8
56  2019-01     20
57  2019-01      5
```

Solution with converting column to `datetime`s:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%m')

df = df[df['Date'].ne(df['Date'].max())]
print (df)
         Date  Value
49 2018-11-01      6
50 2018-12-01      8
51 2018-12-01      2
52 2018-12-01      5
53 2018-12-01      2
54 2018-12-01     14
55 2019-01-01      8
56 2019-01-01     20
57 2019-01-01      5
```